# Popup Window With Specific Size

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a pop-up window similar to how [Origin](http://www.origin.com/ca/about) (click on the 'Log In' does it (pops up in another window with a specific size). I've tried going through their code but I cannot find out how they are doing it. I tried Googling this issue and someone said to use `window.open`, but I cannot find on the Origin website any reference to this code. I've also noticed that the when viewing the Origin website on IE, clicking the 'Log In' link will open the page in the same window as oppose to popping up another window. Is there some sort of IE detection going on? Why would Origin do that only for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be using `window.open` in an external JS file. Basically, they use that to open up a login page and saves all the login stuff in what is called PHP Sessions.

It might not work in IE because IE doesn't support a lot of the newer technologies that are being used right now. Honestly, it's better to make the login page on the same window, because some browsers might disable popups, or some users might just find popup windows annoying.

Comment: I was investigating the pop-up window and it seems to be coming from another domain. Could this be why they are using a pop-up?

Comment: They're probably using a popup to manage the location of the user. I notice that the login page has a `/ca` attached to mine because I'm from Canada. It's most likely the login button directs to another page that finds your location and displays the correct page for you. Just for management purposes. Why do you want to make a popup page in the first place?

Comment: Its for a school assignment. Thanks for answering my question though :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
window.open('your page location', 'pop out window's title', 'width=850px,height=600px,top=200px,left=400px,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
```